# Changing margins of a page without closing it in an enviroment

Tags: margins, geometry, afterpage, changepage

my thesis needs to change margins if i have to put an image on the side of the page; however, i can't use geometry package (since it has a \clearpage both at \newgeometry and \restoregeometry); changepage seems better for this, but it edits margins only for the text inside its enviroment; i could technically use any of those two with \afterpage to make margin change till end of page, but there's not \startpage or \beginpage to do the opposite and automatically enclose the page in the enviroment/geometry commands.
Any ideas?

Comment: It is easier to overlap margins than change them anyway.  KOMA uses negative `\leftskip` and/or `\rightskip` to do this.  I prefer a minipage with negative `\hspace*` before and/or after.

Comment: Ok, but these don't slove my problem, since they only affect the current paragraph. If i change paragraph i need the previous one to change margins as well, but only for the part that's in the page. 
I need a command that edits the margins of the page it's placed on, regardless of where that page starts.

Comment: You can use flowfram to place a different margin on any page, but you will need to manually break paragraphs across pages if the margins change.  Usually universities have rules about what the margins have to be anyway.

Comment: Mine doesn't have a fixed margin, fortunately. But yeah breaking paragraphs manually defies the purpose. May this be doable with a trasparent figure to float maybe? I would need to make it start at the top of the page tho

Comment: You can use a [p] float and a large minipage.  It won't affect the header, but you probably want to suppress the header on those pages (see floatpag package).

Comment: I didn't think about that! Thanks :)